# How to use sessions with pymongo and Flask-Login?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am developing a web based application using flask and mongoDB. for db connection and operations I am using pymongo. So far I am successful in doing User registration and User login but when I used @login_required decorator and added @login_manager.user_loader my login had stopped working and not giving any errors. On debugging into it I found out the problem is session ID. I am getting the Session id in

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print("user_id",user_id)
    user =User.get_by_id(user_id)
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        return User(user["_id"])
    else:
        return None
```

but how to use it or manage it using pymongo as when I try to get user data based on session id using

```
user =User.get_by_id(user_id)
```

I am getting None

Comment: Are you calling login_user function from flask_login module to log in your current user?

Comment: yes i am using login_user function

Comment: current_user() is a function from the same module for getting the current user. Are you also using it somewhere else?

Comment: No I am not using it anywhere in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using current_user attribute, I think this is a good way to go. I will explain following an application I've been working on.

First, I register the user when he logs in:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_require

login = Blueprint('Login', __name__)

@login.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def loginMethod():
    ... 
    db = Database() 
    user = db.selectIf(...)
    login_user(user)

@login.route('/logout')
@login_required 
def logout():
    logout_user()
    ....
```

When I need, I load user using the current_user attribute as below:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_login import login_required, current_user

page = Blueprint('page', __name__)

@page.route('/page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def openPage():
    ... 
    user = current_user
```